# Azure SQL: Can not create a database from a bacpac file using Azure AD user, SQL user on the same server works fine

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am setting up a new environment for a application we have in Azure.
We have a previous setup but trying to make it more secure. In the previous setup we used one user on the database as a SQL user. I want to avoid that and use the Azure AD identity to log in. I have no problem doing that by the SQL Server Management Studio 19.1.
However when I try to create a new database from backups using the Azure AD it will run for a while and then return Failed.
The same thing is happening if I try to export out a bacpac file from a database created on the SQL User log in.
Am I missing any rights on my Azure AD identity, it has the owner right in the system.

I also added a user group that should have access and they can use the SSMS to access the current database select data and create an export from SSMS

Set the user log in to only use Azure AD log in although I can only get it to work with the SQL Admin login

Comment: Hi, Can you share the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]
The problems I had using the Azure Portal to create a new database from a Backpack file is related to our usage of MFA by the phone.
The same operations can be performed in SQL server Management Studio.

It think it is the MFA on the user login creating the problem in the portal, using the SSMS all working fine. I can do the import/export needed in SSMS instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).